# Is the following Sum inequality true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

Ι got a feeling that $$\sum_{m=1}^{N}\Big\lvert \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{m^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}(-1)^{k}\Big\rvert \geq C \sum_{m=1}^{N} \frac{1}{m} $$ Does it exist a $n_o$ such that for every $N\geq n_0$ the above is true?

$$\sum_{m=1}^{N} \Big\lvert 1-\frac{m^2}{3!}+\frac{m^4}{5!}... \Big\rvert \geq C+\frac{C}{2}+\frac{C}{3}... + \frac{C}{N}$$ i feel that somehow terms will get canceled for big enough N, but i cant prove it!!  ( $ m \in N$) and $0< C<1$ constant.

**this came up as a part of problem i was solving . I got no idea if the above inequallity is true got no clue how to approach it!**

Comment: The right side of each is $+\infty.$ Is there a typo, maybe they should be alternating series?

Comment: @coffeemath better or worse now?

Comment: The second formula is not the same as the first one. It should be $1-\dfrac{m^2}2+\dfrac{m^4}{3!}-\dfrac{m^6}{4!}+...$ inside the absolute value. Or the sum in the first formula should be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\dfrac{m^{2k}}{(2k+1)}!=\dfrac{\sin m}{m}$.

Comment: @LutzL check again!

Comment: Yes, now the formulas are the same. So you want to claim $$\sum_{m=1}^N\frac{|\sin m|}m\ge C\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1m.$$ This could be complicated as $|\sin m|$ can be arbitrarily small, the sequence of the $|\sin m|$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Thus you need some kind of avaraging argument where the larger values balance out the small values.

Comment: @LutzL yes exactly.

Comment: Manolis-- Yes, better now that the sum stops.

Comment: Just to test: if you replace $m$ with $\pi m$ would you get the same feeling of cancellation for big $N$ or what would be principally different with the series $$\sum_{m=1}^N\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\pi^{2k}m^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}(-1)^k\right|$$

Comment: @A.Γ. i dont see what you are trying to point me sorry.Ill just have a constant factor that keep getting bigger?

Comment: I am trying to trigger your intuition: if you still feel that it is true then something is wrong because $\sin\pi m=0$ and there is no such $C$ for sure in this case.

Comment: my intuition does not come from looking at the series in the snx/x form although i know they are the same. i just look at those fractions and im thinking while N gets big the 1/N gets small easier to be canceled by the right side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner sum is $\sin m /m$ and

$$\sum_{m=1}^N \frac{|\sin m|}{m} \geqslant \sum_{m=1}^N \frac{|\sin m|^2}{m}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^N \frac{1}{m} - \sum_{m=1}^N \frac{\cos 2m}{2m}$$.

Since the second series on the RHS converges (by the Dirichlet test) we have

$$\sum_{m=1}^N \frac{|\sin m|}{m} \geqslant  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^N \frac{1}{m} - K,$$

where $K \approx -0.2603$ for sufficiently large $N$ and your result holds for  $C = 1/2$.

Comment: Perfect!!! Nice trick.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis: Your welcome.  I made a minor edit since the LHS is eventually greater than what is shown with $K \approx -0.2603$ (the sum to four decimal places) but not for all $N \geqslant 1$.